# The number of files in tags directory under .git/refs is different in repo and clone

Tags: git, github

I created a clone of one git repository and created a cron to pull the changes into clone periodically as i needed the clone only for reference purposes and not as a working copy. But when i see in the repository under .git/refs/tags there are around 309 tags files but under clone in same path only 13 files. How ever when i use git tag -l command all the tags are listed in both repository and in clone.

Is it expected or i am doing some thing wrong.

PS. I tested out creating a clone and saw that tags directory was empty.

Just wanted to know if this will cause any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are stored in two forms: "loose", in `.git/refs/`, and "packed", in `.git/packed-refs`.

Packed references are faster to use, so a new clone generally has *only* the packed copies.  New and modified references are created loose, though, as these are faster to *update* (just more work to *read*).

On occasion, or when directed, git will repack references (with [`git pack-refs`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html), which is automatically run from [`git gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html), which is automatically run occasionally).